# How did Hannah and Tony meet in "13 Reasons Why"?

Tags: 13-reasons-why

I remember Tony helped Hannah when her car battery dies at the Winter Formal dance (season 1, episode 5). But I kind of remember they had met before. Does anybody remember when did they meet for the first time? And on what episode was that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As much I remember Hannah first met Tony at the Winter Formal Dance where Tony played the beautiful song "The Night We Met".
Try to remember the conversation between them. Tony gave Hannah the tape of that song.
She gave him the box of 13 tapes because, Hannah knows that Tony love to listen music from tapes and she also borrowed the tape recording stuffs from a Tony.